# How to deep-link to ReVo entries?

Tags: discussion

The "Reta Vortaro" ("ReVo" for short) on http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/ uses frames.

When you use the search field in the right frame, the resulting matches will be shown in the left frame. When you click one of the matches in the left frame, the corresponding dictionary entry will be displayed in the right frame. If you click on the wavy arrow on a dictionary entry in the right frame, the corresponding thesaurus entries will be listed in the left frame etc.

When referring to a dictionary entry in ReVo on esperanto.SE, should I link to the right-frame or left-frame content? Or is there a way to link to the frameset and control both frames?

Comment: http://www.simplavortaro.org/ has the same definitions as ReVo, and doesn't use frames. Though as far as I can see, it doesn't show all the details that ReVo does (synonyms etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on a match in the left frame, you can copy the link ("Copy link address" in Chrome), that link will refer to the right frame content.

I haven't found a way to link to the frameset with both frames.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's possible to link to searches with the following syntax:

```
http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1c.html?q={search query}
```

where `{search query}` is a query you'd enter into ReVo's search field (but URL encoded). E.g., to search for *koramiko*, use http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1c.html?q=koramiko.

The same placeholders (wildcards) as in the search field are supported:

- `_`: single character
- `%`: arbitrary number of characters

To find both *koramiko* **and** *koramik**in**o* (and any other terms beginning with `koramik` and ending with `o`, if any), use http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1c.html?q=koramik%o.

To find all four-letter words (literally, not neccesarily profanities), use http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1c.html?q=____.

I've learned about this feature today (2021-01-27), at the same time as I noticed that ReVo has a new design. Whether this feature was there before or was added just recently in this overhaul, I don't know.